# Use information generated by existing passes in new pass, LLVM

Tags: llvm

I want to ask is that can we use the information generated by existing passes into a new pass?
If yes, then how ?
For example -loops gives the natural loop information, so can we use this information into new pass by calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark a pass as depending on another pass by overriding `getAnalysisUsage()` in the depending pass, then access the instance of that pass by calling `getAnalysis()`. You can then invoke whatever methods you want on that instance to get information out of it.